# How to get only added/changed lines in diff?

Tags: shell, diff

**a.txt**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

**b.txt**

```
10
2
3
40
50
6
70
```

I'd like to run some command on these files that generates the following output.

```
10
40
50
70
```

How can I run a diff on two files but *only* show lines that changed. I don't want any other metadata around the output.

I also don't want to see any context around the changed lines.

Comment: Can't you just write a utility program to do this for you? Maybe I'm thinking your problem is a lot more simplified than it really is...

Comment: @MillieSmith my problem is so simple that I'm certain there's already a unix command for it.

Comment: Hahaha. Ok, fair point.

Comment: You're *not* looking for a *diff* you're looking for `b-a` which is a totally different thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
comm -1 -3 a.txt b.txt
```

comm, common lines, is a handy command.

Comment: hmm, when i use this on my actual files, it's still including some files that are the same in each file :s

Comment: I posted an answer that might work for other people that are experiencing the same problem as me.

Comment: I'm still marking this as accepted because this answer *should* work. My files are probably just wonky or something.

Comment: Yeah, my answer can actually be a little misleading.  Column 1 of comm is lines unique to file 1, column 2 is lines unique to file 2 and column 3 is the common lines to both files.

Comment: Another attack vector is  ``sdiff -s a.txt b.txt`` and look for the bar, less-than and greater-than symbols.

Answer (score 4):

Actually I like Brian's answer using "comm" a lot. It was new to me and works for me.

My more complicated method would be to use a chain of diff, grep and then sed to remove the first two characters.

```
diff a.txt  b.txt  | grep ">" | sed  s/..//
```

Not beautiful, not bullet-proof, but a quick hack.

Answer (score 1):

@Brian Tiffin's answer may work for some people.

If you're having trouble with it, I was able to get this working

```
$ diff -U0 a.txt b.txt | grep ^+ | sed -e /s^+//
```